# Which of the following are valid C++ variable names?

Tags: c++, variables

9index, break, user_name, CONSTANT, _member

Got this wrong on a test and I'm wondering where I can find the right answer. Would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Open your IDE, assign variables to each variable name, then you can get your answer.

Comment: [Here's where you can find the right answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Answer (score 2):

'9index' is wrong. You never start a variable name with numbers. After the first digit is okay.

'break' is a reserved word

Comment: break is a keyword

Comment: You right, I missed that

Answer (score 2):

`9index` is not a valid identifier because it starts with a digit.

`break` is not a valid identifier because it is a language keyword.

`user_name` is a valid identifier.

`CONSTANT` is a valid identifier

`_member` may or may not be a valid identifier.   The standard explicitly reservies a number of identifiers for use by the implementation (e.g. the compiler or standard library).     Identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved at global scope, but not in other scopes (e.g. to name variables of automatic storage duration within a function).    The danger with using reserved identifiers is that no diagnostic is required (i.e. the code can successfully compile) and the code has undefined behaviour.

Anything that is not a valid identifier cannot be used as a variable name (among other things).

Answer (score 0):

All variable names must begin with a letter of the alphabet or an
underscore( _ ). You also cannot use reserved keywords. user_name and _member are valid, the rest aren't. 
-edit- missed the CONSTANT not being CONST as mentioned in another answer.

Comment: `_member` is not valid in global scope, though. Global identifiers are not allowed to begin with an underscore, that is reserved by the language implementation only

Comment: @RemyLebeau good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- 9index - NO.  Variables cannot begin with numbers.
- break - NO. This is a keyword so cannot be a variable name
- user_name - YES.
- CONSTANT - YES. If the variable is called `CONSTANT` **and not** `const`
- _member - YES. Member variables are allowed to begin with underscore

Comment: "*Variables are allowed to begin with underscore*" - except in global scope, they are not.

Comment: Thanks Remy, I hadn't thought about using _ in global scope before.  Changed answer to reflect that.